# Are responses to answers (as another answer) fine to post?

Tags: support, answers

I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69759431/15781079) a question and someone basically responded to my answer in another answer. [Their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69759467/15781079) doesn't work without mine, and in the comments, they say they cited my answer and my answer was incomplete. I don't think responding to an answer with an answer is fine, especially with over 50 rep. Is it fine?

Here's a screenshot of their now deleted post:
[image: Needs my answer to make sense]

Comment: it.... depends. first and foremost, the answer should be useful on it's own. If that means it needs to include some of another answer directly within it, it can, but it must properly cite the other answer as the source and actually provide something of benefit rather than just being a repeat of an existing answer. In this case, I think they failed that second point. Your answer already provides the bit of code that must be updated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They usually are not fine. Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum. You can't reply to an answer with another answer. You can't reply to comments with answers either. One can refer to an existing answer in the new answer, but the new post has to be an answer on its own.

If you think the answer is not a standalone answer, then please flag for a moderator's attention clearly explaining your reasoning and asking for it to be deleted. Note that someone without expertise in the technology might not know whether the new answer is a comment to your post or a counter-answer.

However, it's usually ok to post an answer that suggests the same solution but explains it in a better way. If the original idea for the solution came from another answer then a proper attribution is required. The new answer needs to be comprehensible even when the answer it refers to gets deleted. Repeating the same solution without improving upon it is not acceptable and should be flagged for moderator's attention.

Comment: Agreed. If the answer to the question can be answered with a *direct* link to another question, I'd be considering whether the question should actually be closed as a duplicate. If not, I think it's okay to reference another answer while explaining the differences between what that answer entails and what OP is asking. [Here is an example answer where I did this recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69744182/584676). The OP was trying to do the same thing as the other asker but in a different context and program, and the way the questions are presented they are not duplicates of each other.